# A word or phrase for making a process more difficult, as a means of discouraging or preventing somebody from completing the process

Tags: politics

Today, the FBI announced that Freedom of Information requests would no longer be taken via email. In my opinion, their goal is to reduce the number of FOI requests by making them more difficult to submit.

To put it another way: some websites use a "pay wall," thereby preventing you from accessing its content until you provide payment. I think of this as a sort of "convenience wall," increasing the amount of inconvenience necessary to access content.

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe this concept. Any ideas?

Comment: A paywall isn't there to make it more difficult to access the content, it's there because the content provider wants to make money! That's totally different from your FBI FOI example.

Comment: It depends on the circumstances: when applied to voting it should be called  voter fraud.

Comment: Your question title could apply to this website... a user must create a profile prior to participating.  I doubt many would call that "obstructionism".  Adding the example of FOI requests will probably get some stronger replies.

Comment: @Airymouse:  There need to be barriers to voting in order to prevent cheating.  For example, should voting by email be allowed... how about texting?  How about completely anonymous voting... just walk into any voting location and push a button?

Comment: @James Of course, there need to be barriers to voting to prevent cheating. But if you put up barriers in order to make voting "more difficult, as a means of discouraging someone from" voting, that is voter fraud. I suspect there is little or no such fraud in Canada, Australia, or the UK, but here in the US, especially in the South , where I live, there's plenty of it. You and I agree, I think: the appropriate word or phrase depends on the purpose of the obstruction. It can be as innocent as requiring a user profile or as pernicious as voter fraud.(I prefer "obstruction" to "obstructionism.")

Comment: @Airymouse: You make a good point about how barriers to voting would be voting fraud if the INTENT of the barriers was to discourage voting.

Answer (score 3):

In  formal contexts it is called ***[obstructionism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obstructionism://)***:

> - the act of intentionally stopping or slowing down an official process.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: +1 this is it. I was thinking of _obscurantism_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about "*[to discourage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discourage)*" as a milder form?

Answer (score 0):

Preventing someone from achieving their task could be boycotting, censoring, restricting, impeding, refraining from.